# Migrating VB.Net Access to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013, oledb

I have a fairly large VB.Net WinForms application that I have inherited that uses Access for it's database. The tables and views are all pretty generic, and migrating the database to SQL Server 2012 and amending the Views was a pretty trouble free, if tedious, task.

I'd now like to change the application to use this database. The program has 99% of it's data access defined in XSD files to which it connects using Ole. There's a few direct `OleDbConnections`, but not many.

If program connects to an Access file on startup by setting a connection string, however if I change this to a (valid) connection string pointing at my local SQL Server database I throw an `OleDBException` exception on the first read of

> Not a valid file name

originating from the JET database engine, so I'm obviously missing a change I need.  I've already replaced the connection strings in `app.config` and the XSD files appear to open fine.

In general then, what should I be checking to ensure the application will use SQL Server instead of Ole.

Comment: You dont just change the connection string, but (should) change the db provider from OleDB to `System.Data.SQLClient` (if I understand the question right)

Comment: Thanks, my VB is a bit rusty unfortunately, where in the labyrinth of VS would I find where that is specified for the solution?

Comment: `Imports System.Data.SqlClient` would make all the SQL Server related provider objects available to that class/form. add a reference to `System.Data` if needed

Comment: Usually the connectionstring informations is kept in the app.config file, and adding to what @Plutonix said you should remove the Imports System.Data.OleDb line wherever you find it. This will trigger compilation errors in each file that tries to use this library and you could (tediously) fix the errors.

Comment: ...it will mean recoding `OleDbConnection` references (for example) to `SqlConnection`.  But there are loads of other things you might want to change because the optimal way to use OleDB is not always optimal for SQLSvr...the first hurdle though will be converting code to use `sqlClient` provider objects...and the project ought to already have a reference to `System.Data` because that is where OleDB is as well (brain misfired)

Comment: The application was developed by a competent but inexperienced developer re databases, so the OleDB usage is very suboptimal anyway